# How to get selected values from datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm fitghting with this all weekend, so i hope that here can i find the answer:

I'm usising http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html with calls at the server side with json but i can't get the selected items from the datatable to set it in a input hidden (to pass trough an Struts Actions for backend process), so the selection of the data works fine, but i can't find in the DataTable API how to get the values of the rows selected to do some like:

```
$("#myHiddenValues").val(datatableSelectedValues);
```

Where the var datatableSelectedValues is the array with the rowsId (or some other objects) with the data that i need,

Thanks :)

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()

Comment: well using: console.log("selected: " + table.rows( { selected: true } ).data()); in the on(click) method of the table the result of the console is: selected: [object Object] so the questions is now ¿how to convert the [object Object] to values that i can use?

Comment: you must iterate the array of objects, check this example https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/40/

Comment: thx, that is i need, may be if you wanna explain a little more can do an answer, if not, when i have some time i would post a full answer to this question thx you very much :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`table.rows({selected: true}).data())` returns an array of objects that you selected to access objects must iterate and access them by index. For example if you need show `name` , `position` and `office` :

**HTML CODE**

```
<table id="example" class="display DataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var pos = oTable.row(this).index();
    var row = oTable.row(pos).data();
    console.log(row);
} );

$('#button').click( function () {
    var oData = oTable.rows('.selected').data();

    for (var i=0; i < oData.length ;i++){
       alert("Name: " + oData[i][0] + " Position: " + oData[i][1] + " Office: " + oData[i][2]);
    }

} );
} );
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/40/